# The requested package ... could not be found in any version

Tags: php, git, composer-php

When I want to require my project, the following errors shows up:

*The requested package mvc-php/framework could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.*

The "mvc-php/framework" is a git folder.

```
{
    "name": "mvc-php/app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/Users/youri/Documents/Github/framework"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "mvc-php/framework": "master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

Project i want to require:

```
{
    "name": "mvc-php/framework",
    "description": "PHP MVC framework",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mvc\\" : "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of just the branch name, you must require `branchName@dev`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches

```
{
    "name": "mvc-php/app",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/Users/youri/Documents/Github/framework"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "mvc-php/framework": "master@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `master@dev` not worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

> The requested package X/Y could not be found in any version.

The requested package needs to be a git folder with the committed and existing `composer.json` file. Then to reference specific branch, you need to add the `dev-` prefix, so `dev-master`, **not `master`**.

#### Example

Here is the minimal working example:

File: **`composer.json`**

```
{
  "require": {
    "local/my_package": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "packagist.org": false
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "my_package/"
    }
  ]
}
```

File: **`my_package/composer.json`**

```
{
  "name": "local/my_package",
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/console": "*"
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: Above file is under local Git repository. To create one, run: `git init && git commit -am 'Files'`.</sup>

#### [Troubleshooting](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md)

To troubleshoot the issue, run:

```
composer install -vvv
```

Also consider running: `composer diagnose` to identify common *Composer* errors.

Comment: Can't believe this has no upvote. Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: That `-vvv` is gold.

Answer (score 14):

As this is the first response when searching the error text on Google, I will also put my fix here, despite not being 100% relevant to the OP.

When you are requiring the repo, you need to make sure that your requires statement matches the name of the project in the composer.json of the project.

So if the name had been `"name": "mvc-php/app-framework",` in the framework project, then the require would need to be:

```
"require": {
  "mvc-php/app-framework": "dev-master"
},
```

This is more applicable when you are adding a git repo. Especially when forking, as sometimes the git url might be different from the composer.json name.

Additionally (and this is the part relevant to OP), you now need to do `dev-branch_name` instead of `branch_name@dev` when requiring. I don't know when this changed, or if the old method is unusable. But this is what the current composer docs now say.

> If you want Composer to check out a branch instead of a tag, you need to point it to the branch using the special `dev-*` prefix
>   <sub>[Composer Documentation - Versions and Constraints - Branches](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches)</sub>

Comment: Hey this answer saved my days. I was unaware of the **name** repository naming. Thanks

Comment: note that it seems like the `master`/default branch seems to need this, even if you are requesting/requiring a different branch.

Comment: My problem solved using this simple trick. `name` in your package's `composer.json` should match the required name in your app's `composer.json`.

Answer (score 12):

#### Another Gotcha to be Aware Of:

I changed the name of a package I developed and was just testing a branch on it. I had followed all the correct naming conventions mentioned above but was still getting the given error.

It turns out that for the name change to be picked up, you have to update the package name in `composer.json` on the main branch of the package repo (`Master` for me) even if you are not using that branch within your project.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that if you do not add your own mirror source to the global variable, an error will occur where the sub-scene is not found.
You can add this in composer.json:

```
"repositories":[
 {
  "type":"composer",
  "url":"https://packag"
 }
],
```